# How does cplex allocate memory to a IloExpr type?

Tags: c++

My algorithm aborts before finalizing the creation of the objective function of my problem. Following the use of my computer's memory, I can see that it overflows. In terminal, the message: "killed" appears. The part of the code which I'm having trouble is:

```
IloEnv env = monoD.env;
monoD.mod = IloModel(env); 
monoD.cplex = IloCplex(monoD.mod);

monoD.beta = IloNumVarArray(env, Dbeta.size(), 0, +IloInfinity,ILOFLOAT);

IloExpr xpfo(env);
for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++){ 
  for (int j = 0; j < 18; j++){ 
    if (w[i][j] != 0){
      for (int u = 19; u <= 35; u++) { 
        for (int v = 19; v <= 35; v++) {
          if (isE(u,v)) {
            xpfo = xpfo - monoD.beta[i,j,u,v]; 
          }
        } 
        for (int u = 36; u <= 52; u++) { 
          for (int v = 36; v <= 52; v++) { 
            if (isE(u,v)) {
              xpfo = xpfo - monoD.beta[i,j,u,v]; 
            }
          }
       }
    }
  }
}

monoD.fo = IloAdd(monoD.mod, IloMaximize(env, xpfo));
xpfo.end();
```

I know that I have a lot of variables, but in ampl I can solve this instance without any problem. The other interesting thing is that when I utilize Gurobi for the same implementation, I don't have memory's problem. Then, I want to know if I am doing something wrong or if can be cplex's problem. Anyone knows how does cplex allocate memory to a IloExpr type?

Thank you!